# Retrieve polyline coordinates from maps.google.com

Tags: javascript, google-maps, bookmarklet

I want to write a bookmarklet to take the polyline coordinates for an existing (i.e. currently displayed) route on a Google Map and do some processing.  Since maps.google.com already has a nice implementation of putting in coordinates and selecting a route, I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.  Is there a clean way I can let a user select a route on maps.google.com and then have my bookmarklet get the coordinates for the displayed route?

I tried digging around the `window` object a bit but didn't find anything.  I've seen implementations of this where you load the entire page source into a string and then process the string for id `route0`, `route1`, etc., but is there a better way?

Comment: I suppose slightly cleaner would be to pull the selected coordinates of the endpoints and along the route from the UI and then use the Direction API to reload the paths.  Assuming these are available in the UI under all conditions...